# How to skip first element of List in c:forEach

Tags: list, foreach, jstl, skip

I'm using `<c:forEach>` to iterate over a `List` like below:

```
<c:forEach items="${list}" var="item">
    ${item}
</c:forEach>
```

How can I skip printing of the first item of the list?

Comment: @BalusC: It's List<List> . I am populating few values on hovering over button - element.first/second/third/fourth.get(0)  . Hope it is clear now

Comment: @BalusC: i have added more description. I want some help to access the value of List inside List

Comment: @BalusC: I have solved that issue, just need small help now. I have changed my question. Plz have a look

Comment: You'd possibly do better putting first, second, third and fourth in an array or list to start with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `varStatus` attribute to get hold of the [iteration status](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus.html) which in turn has among others a [`isFirst()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus.html#isFirst--) method which you could check in a `<c:if>` block.

```
<c:forEach items="${list}" var="item" varStatus="loop">
    <c:if test="${not loop.first}">
        ${item}
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 7):

Use  `varStatus` in your `forEach` and an `if` test

```
<c:forEach items="${list}" var="item" varStatus="state">
    <c:if test="${not state.first}">
       ${item}
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Other [useful varStatus properties](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jstl0318/) are:

- `current` The item (from the collection) for the current round of iteration
- `index`       The zero-based index for the current round of iteration
- `count`     The one-based count for the current round of iteration
- `first`       Flag indicating whether the current round is the first pass through the iteration
- `last`        Flag indicating whether the current round is the last pass through the iteration
- `begin`       The value of the begin attribute
- `end`     The value of the end attribute
- `step`      The value of the step attribute